# private bool in web service

Tags: web-services, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I have a web service which accepts XML and passes from one system into BizTalk for routing to another system.

The service seems to contain a private bool which is stopping one particular element from getting through the service, every other one gets through OK.
e.g. if I have fields A, B, C, D, the private bool does not allow D to get through, so what is routed through BizTalk is the XML message minus D.

Looking for some idea where to start with this one.

Comment: it is not clear from the question what is it you want: if you want to change the running service it's one thing, but it is often easier to request assistance from the team who owns that service code. Consider revising. It is also not clear which service has private bool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can run codez in service app domain, you can use reflection to change the private bool.

But if you run outside of service app domain, you're pretty much bound by rules of service contract. But then again, how do you know about existence of private bool inside the service then?